# CLI Hangman game in C++

Tags: c++, game, hangman

Well this is a basic hangman game in c++ without the classy man getting hanged animation (life is printed instead)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string previousGuesses;     //string to hold previous guesses

class movie {
    private:
        string name;
        int _size;

    public:
        movie(void);
        inline string getName(void) {
            return this->name;
        }
        inline int getSize(void) {
            return this->_size;
        }
};

movie::movie(void) {
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("movies.txt", ios::in);
    // int random_integer = rand();
    getline(fin, this->name);       //currently takes the first line as movie name. Randomising logic will be inserted....any hints??
    this->_size = name.size();
    fin.close();
}

int numOfSpaces(string name) {
    register unsigned counter = 0;
    for (register int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
        if(name[i] == ' ') {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

bool guessedPreviously(char ch) {
    if(previousGuesses.find(ch) != -1) {        //if guess is found, return true
        return true;
    }
    previousGuesses += ch;
    return false;
}

void print(char name[], int size) {
    for (register int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << name[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    /*to get name of the movie*/
    srand(time(NULL)); //seed for rand();
    register int counter = 0;   //used to check if the full guess has been finally made though better logic is welcome
    register int life = 10;     //hold the lives user has
    movie m1;           //object of movie class
    char name[m1.getSize()];    //temp char[] (used to mask/unmask movie name)
    char guess;                 //shall hold user's guess
    string _name = m1.getName();    //a variable to store the movie name (needed as m1.getName()[i] surprisingly doesn't work....why??)
    for (register int i = 0; i < m1.getSize(); i++) {
        /*logic to keep spaces, spaces in the temp char[]*/
        if(_name[i] != ' ')
            name[i] = '*';
        else
            name[i] = ' ';
    }
    while (1) {     //runs the game loop
        /*User's guess*/
        cout << "Enter a guess: ";
        cin >> guess;
        if(guessedPreviously(guess)) {
            cout << "guess already made!!" << endl;
            life--;
            cout << life << endl;
            if (life == 0) {
                cout << "game over!!!" << endl;
                cout << m1.getName() << endl;
                exit(0);
            }
            continue;
        }
        cout << endl;               //I/O formatting ...... because we need it!!
        /*check guess*/
        bool check = false;         //boolean variable to umm.. not let the else if get unnecessarily executed
        for (register int i = 0; i < _name.size(); i++) {
            if(_name[i] == guess) {
                name[i] = guess;    //replaces * in temporary char[] at all places where guess is correct
                check = true;
                /*To check if the full guess has finally been made!!*/
                counter++;
                if(counter == (m1.getSize() - numOfSpaces(m1.getName()))) {     //m1.getSize() also returns spaces, which are not being guessed
                    cout << "congrats!! You've won" << endl;
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
            else if (i == _name.size() - 1 && !check) {     //the 'what to do if guess is wrong??' logic
                cout << "wrong guess!!" << endl;
                life--;     //kill the user once XD
                cout << "You have " << life << " guesses left!!" << endl;
                if (life == 0) {
                    cout << "game over!!!" << endl;
                    cout << m1.getName() << endl;
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
        /*unmask*/
        print(name, m1.getSize());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

All kinds of improvements are welcome :)

Also how do I make the code case insensitive efficiently??

BTW, the repository is public [here](https://github.com/d4rk4ng31/cpp-projects)

Comment: I added the tag _game_ which is the generic tag accompanying any specific game tag. You don't see this change at the revision (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/227619/3)  But you do see it at the revision overview (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/227619/revisions).

Comment: No offense taken :) I am surprised to see a revision does not show tag edits.

Comment: @Mast I am not sure whether this is as designed or not. But I'm not concerned about it either :) If it's a bug, it's hypo minor :p

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  Similar questions are fine on Code Review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review!  Here's some suggestions.

## Overall design

You defined a class `movie`.  Despite its name, all it does is read a string from the configuration file `movies.txt`.  This is unnecessary — just write a function that reads a string.

The global variable `previousGuesses` contains the previous guesses.  This shows that the game is stateful.  This is a good use for classes:

```
class Hangman_game {
public:
    // ...
private:
    std::string word;
    std::string guesses;
};
```

The `numOfSpaces` function can be replaced by `std::count`.  The `print` function is unnecessary.  And it is counter-intuitive that `guessedPreviously` modifies the `previousGuesses`.

You are using char arrays all over the place.  In C++, prefer `std::string` for actual strings.

## Code

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <cstdlib>
> #include <string.h>
> #include <time.h>
> #include <fstream>
> ```

Use `<cstring>` and `<ctime>`.  And sort the headers alphabetically:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
```

> ```
> using namespace std;
> ```

Do not use `using namespace std;`.  It is considered [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721) and will cause a lot of problems.  For example, you will have some trouble using common identifiers like `size`.

> ```
> class movie {
>     private:
>         string name;
>         int _size;
>
>     public:
>         movie(void);
>         inline string getName(void) {
>             return this->name;
>         }
>         inline int getSize(void) {
>             return this->_size;
>         }
> };
> ```

1. `inline` is redundant in a class.
2. `(void)` is C-style and is not recommended in C++.  Use `()` instead.
3. `this->` is unnecessary.
4. `std::string` maintains the size, so `_size` should be removed.

`public:` and `private:` are usually not indented.  And as I said before, this class should not exist at all.

> ```
> movie::movie(void) {
>     ifstream fin;
>     fin.open("movies.txt", ios::in);
>     // int random_integer = rand();
>     getline(fin, this->name);       //currently takes the first line as movie name. Randomising logic will be inserted....any hints??
>     this->_size = name.size();
>     fin.close();
> }
> ```

The same thing with compact code:

```
std::ifstream fin{"movies.txt"}; // the default is "in"
std::getline(fin, name);
```

Also, `"movies.txt"` should not be hardcoded.

> ```
> int numOfSpaces(string name) {
>     register unsigned counter = 0;
>     for (register int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
>         if(name[i] == ' ') {
>             counter++;
>         }
>     }
>     return counter;
> }
> ```

The keyword `register` is completely ignored by the compiler.  Also, use

```
std::count(name.begin(), name.end(), ' ')
```

instead.

> ```
> bool guessedPreviously(char ch) {
>     if(previousGuesses.find(ch) != -1) {        //if guess is found, return true
>         return true;
>     }
>     previousGuesses += ch;
>     return false;
> }
> ```

Use `std::string::npos` instead of `-1`.  The latter is counter-intuitive and may cause signedness warnings.

> ```
> void print(char name[], int size) {
>     for (register int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
>         cout << name[i];
>     }
>     cout << endl;
> }
> ```

You should never be using a `char[]`, but even if that is the case, use `std::cout << std::string_view(name, size) << '\n';`.  [Don't use `std::endl`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907)

---

The main function is too long and looks chaotic.  It should be broken into different functions.  And you are using a variable length array which is a non-standard extension and should not be used.  `std::string` should be used instead.  And there's quite a few problems.  `rand` is infamous for its low quality and should not be used.   Too many variables make the logic hard to understand.  Most of the loops should be replaced by standard algorithms.  `return` is better than `exit(0)`.  Use `++i` instead of `i++` in a discarded value expression.

## Improved version

Here's a very rough version in which I fix the aforementioned problems, not tested extensively:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

class Hangman {
public:
    Hangman(std::string_view w, int l)
        :word{w}, current(w.size(), '_'), lives{l}
    {
        if (w.find('_') != w.npos) {
            throw std::runtime_error{"underscore character not supported"};
        }
    }
    void run();

private:
    std::string word;
    std::string current; // the current state (e.g., "_an_man")
    int lives;           // number of lives left

    enum class State {
        none, win, fail
    };

    void display();
    State guess();
};

void Hangman::run()
{
    State state;
    do {
        display();
        state = guess();
    } while (state == State::none);

    display();
    if (state == State::win) {
        std::cout << "Congratulations!  You win.\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Game over.\n"
                  << "The word is " << std::quoted(word) << '\n';
    }
}

void Hangman::display()
{
    std::cout << "Word: " << current << "\n"
                 "Lives left: " << lives << "\n\n";
}

auto Hangman::guess() -> State
{
    std::cout << "Guess a letter: ";

    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
    if (!std::cin) {
        throw std::runtime_error{"input failure"};
    }

    if (current.find(c) != current.npos) {
        std::cout << "You have already guessed this letter.\n\n";
        --lives;
    } else if (word.find(c) == word.npos) {
        std::cout << "Bad guess.\n\n";
        --lives;
    } else {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i) {
            if (word[i] == c)
                current[i] = c;
        }
        if (word == current)
            return State::win;
    }

    if (lives == 0)
        return State::fail;
    else
        return State::none;
}

int main()
{
    Hangman game{"derivative", 6}; // configuration
    game.run();
}
```

Example session:

```
Word: __________
Lives left: 6

Guess a letter: a
Word: _____a____
Lives left: 6

Guess a letter: b
Bad guess.

Word: _____a____
Lives left: 5

Guess a letter: c
Bad guess.

Word: _____a____
Lives left: 4

Guess a letter: d
Word: d____a____
Lives left: 4

Guess a letter: e
Word: de___a___e
Lives left: 4

Guess a letter: f
Bad guess.

Word: de___a___e
Lives left: 3

Guess a letter: g
Bad guess.

Word: de___a___e
Lives left: 2

Guess a letter: h
Bad guess.

Word: de___a___e
Lives left: 1

Guess a letter: i
Word: de_i_a_i_e
Lives left: 1

Guess a letter: j
Bad guess.

Word: de_i_a_i_e
Lives left: 0

Game over.
The word is "derivative"
```

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 You are welcome.  Essentially, the game needs to keep track of some states (the word, the current guessed letters, lives left), so it is advised to use a class to encapsulate them.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 As I said before, `rand()` is a low-quality RNG and should not be used.  C++11 offers the `<random>` header which contains high-quality RNG.

Comment: Also, is there any specific reason for compiler to ignore `register` keyword?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Yeah, `<random>` is a big one.  You need to construct an engine first (e.g., mt19937) and then use a uniform int distribution to generate an index from, say, 0 to 25.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98394/discussion-between-d4rk4ng31-and-l-f).

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 `register` is specified to have no meaning since C++11, and "poisoned" since C++17 (i.e., using it is ill-formed)

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Good optimizing compilers will do a better job of allocating registers than the author (supposedly). Good optimizing compilers may modify the algorithm  as well.

Comment: Alphabetizing includes may not work in all cases.

Comment: Oh!! But does it work at least in C (still) ?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31I Yeah, it still works in C11 AFAIK, but please note that the notion of "register" doesn't exist in the C or C++ standards, so it exists merely as a recommendation to the implementation.  The recommendation isn't always respected, anyway - the implementation is free to put a non-`register` variable in registers, and free to put a `register` variable outside registers.

Comment: One more thing. I have never seen this syntax. What does `auto Hangman::guess() -> State` do?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 It’s called the “trailing return type” `auto f() -> T` is equivalent to `T f()`